# Light colour - Node Emision colour vs Light colour

Tags: lighting, color

Hi I'm using cycles and have noticed that when using nodes to control lights there are two different light colour inputs 1. The original light colour and 2. the emision light colour.

[image: Two Light colour fields]

Can anyone tell me why this is? or probably more importantly how they interact (Multiply?) and what the best method is for controlling the light colour? If one is left white then the other seems to control the colour otherwise they seem to mix with the most saturated one being more dominant.

Thanks, any insight would be appreciated.